# What happens when an assertion check fails?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Page 56 of the uvm users guide 1.1 states:

The following is a simple example of an assertion check. This assertion verifies the size field of the transfer
is 1, 2, 4, or 8. Otherwise, the assertion fails.

```
function void ubus_master_monitor::check_transfer_size();
    check_transfer_size : assert(trans_collected.size == 1 ||
    trans_collected.size == 2 || trans_collected.size == 4 ||
    trans_collected.size == 8) else begin
    // Call DUT error: Invalid transfer size!
    end
endfunction : check_transfer_size
```

I have a few questions:

A. In the function declaration, what does it mean to declare a function with a name like `some_name::another_name`?

B. How does the function know what `trans_collected` is if it's not declared inside it?

C. What will the `assert` do when some of the conditions are not met?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A**. In `ubus_master_monitor::check_transfer_size`, `ubus_master_monitor` is the name of the class, and `check_transfer_size` is the name of the function.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 8.24 *Out-of-block declarations*:

> It is convenient to be able to move method definitions out of the body
>   of the class declaration.

Inside the class body, there will be a declaration like:

```
class ubus_master_monitor;
    extern function void check_transfer_size();
endclass
```

---

**B**. Presumably, there is a class-level variable named `trans_collected`.

---

**C**. If the `assert` fails, the code in the `else` clause will be executed.  Also, a simulator specific message may be written to the log file and displayed on the console.  Refer to the Std, section 16. *Assertions*.